# How to make a double loop inside a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data cube with 2 dimensions of coordinates and a third dimension for wavelength. My goal is to write a mask for coordinates outside a circle of given radius to the central coordinates (x0 and y0 in my code). For this, I'm trying to use a dictionary, but I'm having throuble because it seems that I'll have to make a double loop inside the dictionary to iterate over the two dimensions, and as a beginner with dictionaries, I don't know yet how to do that.

I wrote the following code

```
x0 = 38
y0 = 45
radius = 9

xcoords = np.arange(1,flux.shape[1]+1,1)
ycoords = np.arange(1,flux.shape[2]+1,1)

mask = {'xmask': [xcoords[np.sqrt((xcoords[:]-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2) < radius] for y in ycoords], 'ymask': [ycoords[np.sqrt((x-x0)**2 + (ycoords[:]-y0)**2) < radius] for x in xcoords]}
```

And it returned several arrays, one for each value of y (for xmasks), and one for each value of x (for ymasks), although I want just one array for each one. Could anyone say what I made wrong and how to achieve my goal?

**Note:** I also made it without using a dictionary, as

```
xmask = []
for x in xcoords:
    for y in ycoords:
        if np.sqrt((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2) < radius:
            xmask.append(x)
            break

ymask = []
for y in xcoords:
    for x in ycoords:
        if np.sqrt((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2) < radius:
            ymask.append(y)
            break
```

but I hope it's possible to make it more efficiently.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** I realized that no loop was needed. If I select y = y0 and x = x0, I get the values of x and y that are inside the circle, respectively. So I stayed with

```
mask = {'xmask': [xcoords[abs(xcoords[:]-x0) < radius]], 'ymask': [ycoords[abs(ycoords[:]-y0) < radius]]}
```

Comment: Your comprehensions have loops.

Comment: You forgot the square parenthesis [] around your list comprehensions (the values in your dict).

Comment: Ups, thanks. And now I just realized I don't need any loop. Just a 
`mask = {'xmask': [xcoords[np.sqrt((xcoords[:]-x0)**2) < radius]], 'ymask': [ycoords[np.sqrt((ycoords[:]-y0)**2) < radius]]}` 
and I get my masks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP explains that assigning

```
mask = {'xmask': [xcoords[abs(xcoords[:] - x0) < radius]],
        'ymask': [ycoords[abs(ycoords[:] - y0) < radius]]}
```

solves the problem.